# How do I borrow a value inside an `or_else` closure after it's been borrowed for a function call?

Tags: rust

I'm making an asset library that's supposed to hold a tree of nodes. A node can be either an `Asset` or a `Directory`:

```
struct Node {
    name: String,
    data: Content,
}

enum Content {
    Directory(Vec<Node>),
    Asset(Rc<dyn Asset>, usize),
}
```

I have a `create_dir_all` method that's supposed to take a path and create all directories. The way I want to do that is to iterate over the components of the path, search for the corresponding node, and if it is found, move on to the next, if I get a `NotFound` error, create the node and then move on.

My first idea was to do this:

```
let mut current_node = &mut self.root;
for component in path.components() {
    let name = component.as_os_str().to_str().unwrap();

    current_node = current_node.get_child(name).or_else(|error| match error {
        ErrorKind::NotFound => {
            current_node.create_child(Node::directory(String::from(name)))
        }
        error => Err(error),
    })?;
}
```

I believe I understand why that doesn't work: the closure has to borrow `current_node` mutably at the time it's created, so the `create_child` call is a second mutable borrow.

However, I can't seem to find any way around that. Here's another attempt:

```
let mut current_node = &mut self.root;
for component in path.components() {
    let name = component.as_os_str().to_str().unwrap();

    current_node = match current_node.get_child(name) {
        Ok(child) => Ok(child),
        Err(error) => match error {
            ErrorKind::NotFound => {
                current_node.create_child(Node::directory(String::from(name)))
            }
            error => Err(error),
        },
    }?;
}
```

Here's my understanding of this one:
The lifetime of `current_node` inside the inner match is the same one that's assigned on the `get_child` call, so the `create_child` call will be a second mutable borrow.

While researching this, I found that the lifetime of the result will be tied to the lifetime of `current_node`. If that's the case, is it impossible to match the error and generate a fallback value? That seems like a very simple thing to do but I cannot figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: You need [Learning Rust with Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html) for anything and everything about linking things together in Rust.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your issue

Answer (score 1):

I had posted this to the Rust forums as well and got a [helpful response](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/use-struct-instance-to-create-default-value-in-case-of-error/82474/3?u=voxelstack) there: the borrow checker "does not recognize a borrow being continued on one arm of a match but terminated on another."

I went with the suggestion from that response and will look into writing some unsafe code here in the future. It looks like this:

```
let mut current_node = &mut self.root;
        for component in path.components() {
            let name = component.as_os_str().to_str().unwrap();

            if let Err(error) = current_node.get_child(name) {
                match error {
                    ErrorKind::NotFound => {
                        current_node.create_child(Node::directory(String::from(name)))
                    }
                    error => Err(error),
                }?;
            }

            current_node = current_node.get_child(name)?;
        }
```